# ViewFlipper Display's Views In The Wrong Order

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project I have an array of three days:

```
 String[] days = {"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

These are added to a ViewFlipper programmatically as shown here:

```
 ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
 TextView textview = new TextView[numDays];
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout[numDays];

 for(int i = 0; i<numDays; i++){
      layout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);           
      vf.addView(layout[i]);

      textview[i] = new TextView(this);
      textview[i].setText(data.days[i].name);           
      layout[i].addView(textview[i]); 
 }
```

But when I go to the ViewFlipper when I load my app it appears in this order:

```
 Friday --- Sunday --- Saturday
```

Does anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] days = {"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

and

```
 strong text  Intent intent=getIntent();
    String selected=intent.getStringExtra("SELECTED",0);    
    int[] Ids=days [selected];        
    System.out.println(selected);

    Flipp = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);          
       for(int i=0; i<Ids.length;i++)
    {
        TextView View=new TextView (this);
        View.setImageResource(Ids[i]);            
        Flipp.addView(View);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?  What specifically causes the flipper content to be in the right order in yours but not in the OP's?